# Concatenating arrays with numpy doesn't work

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
time=3600000    
count=0
l=0
while l<=time:    

    d=[12,37,45,67,98,45,90]
    t=0
    while t<=time:
        Theta_t=d*t
        r=[]
        r.append(Theta_t)
        t+=360

    if count==0:
        Theta=np.array([r])
    else:
        np.concatenate((Theta,[r]),axis=0)
    count+=1
    l+=360
```

Now, my problem is it does not append values to Theta which should be a two dimensional array with every column contains the values of r. Such as, Theta=[[12,56,58,45],[56,87,54,56],[...],...].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Next try:

Instead of

```
np.concatenate((Theta,[r]),axis=0)
```

do

```
Theta = np.concatenate((Theta,[r]),axis=0)
```

Comment: I don't have the values of r before the loop. So, it will not work. If I will create an empty array with zero's for r, outside the loop and then append values, it will not also work for me.

Comment: Here Theta should be a 2 dimensional array and output of theta should look like. Theta=[[12,56,58,45],[56,87,54,56],[...],...]

Comment: Can I append instead of concatenate?